# Put title, done button and remove arrow from popover

Tags: ios, popover

I am trying to create a basic app that has one main view controller and several other view controllers connected using the storyboardID and having those several other view controllers without arrows for the popover and be able to position it any where on the main view controller.

This part of my code always crashes but I do realize it has the arrow direction going up and coming from a bar. Rather it be a regular button.

```
- (IBAction)togglePopover:(id)sender
{

    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [self popover2];

    if(popoverController == nil){

        FlipsideViewController *controller =

        [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popover2"];

        [controller setDelegate:self];

        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];

        [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0)];

        [self setPopover2:popoverController];


        [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[self showInfo]
                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    }
```

Any thing will help. Thanks everyone

Comment: what is the crash message?

Comment: 2014-04-24 11:43:56.422 popover[43744:a0b] -[UIViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa541460
2014-04-24 11:43:56.425 popover[43744:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa541460'

Comment: At a point in that method you are setting the delegate of a view controller which doesn't have a delegate and that is causing your crash. - make sure you have a delegate property to set on 'controller'